# django save data to session without increasing its expiry

Tags: django, session, session-cookies, django-sessions

Basically I want to do something like:

```
request.session['last_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

without django modify (increase) session expire_date (i.e, it should stay as it is)

I have `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`

The session expiry should remain unchanged when last_date is modified as above. However for all other changes expiry should change. I do not want to set it as a global policy for the session.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change the default behavior of the session engine, the usual practice is to write a custom session backend. Fortunately, it isn't very difficult. We will make ours by subclassing [django.contrib.session.backends.db.SessionStore](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py#L13)

from django.contrib.session.backends.db import SessionStore as DbStore

```
class SessionStore(DbStore):

    def load(self):
        try:
            self.current_session = self.model.objects.get(
                session_key=self.session_key,
                expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
            )
            return self.decode(s.session_data)
        except (self.model.DoesNotExist, SuspiciousOperation) as e:
            if isinstance(e, SuspiciousOperation):
                logger = logging.getLogger('django.security.%s' % e.__class__.__name__)
                logger.warning(force_text(e))
            self._session_key = None
            return {}

    def create_model_instance(self, data):
        """
        Return a new instance of the session model object, which represents the
        current session state. Intended to be used for saving the session data
        to the database.
        """
        try:
            expiry = self.current_session.expire_date
        except AttributeError:
            expiry = None

        return self.model(
            session_key=self._get_or_create_session_key(),
            session_data=self.encode(data),
            expire_date=self.get_expiry_date(expiry=expiry),
        )
```

Most of the code is from django.contrib with few slight modificiations. Now all you have to do is to tell django to use our new session store by modifying the settings.py

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'myapp.session'
```

Assuming that you put the above code in a file named session.py

**Response to edit in question**:

This code shows how to modify the session with out changing it's expiry time. Now you mention you want this behavour only if the `last_date` item is changed, make a modification as follows;

```
        expiry = None

        try:
            if current_session.get('last_date') != date.get('last_date') :    
                expiry = self.current_session.expire_date
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this is working? I could not understand. Notice I dont want to change the session expire_date only for this time, not to set it globally like that. That's why I dont understand why to override SessionStore

Comment: And I do not understand your comment at all

Comment: I mean, when I set `request.session['last_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()`, I *don't* want to extend the session expire_date. But for other session updates I have, I want it to behave normally (i.e to extend expire_date when the session is saved.). So it should only be one-time behavior

Comment: So do I still need to override SESSION_ENGINE? And I should override just `create_model_instance` mehod, right?   Second,  is there a way to set the expiry date by myself in the view, leaving it as it is?

Comment: yes as mentioned in my answer you need to set the SESSION_ENGINE. As for sessions and views, I think you really should post a new question on that.